# How do I remove a character from a column of data in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am formatting some data I received.  I have several hundred names of students in Column A, and for some strange reason there is a random `*` placed randomly throughout the names.  I want to programmatically remove all `*` characters from all names.

```
 For x = 2 To 300

        Dim strStudent as String

        //how do i set contents of cell to string strStudent

        strStudent = Replace(strStudent, "*", "") //replace * with nothing

 Next
```

My question is, how do I set the contents of the cell to a strStudent?  Then I can test if I'm doing the replace part right.

Comment: You could just use the Substitute Excel function and not bother with VBA.

Comment: @PollyShaw: If NON VBA method is an option I would go with CTRL+H and then using "~*" as the `Find` criteria :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the cell. You can use Excel's inbuilt `.Replace` function to replace all `*` by using  `"~*"`

Here is an example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Change this to the relevant range
    Set Rng = ws.Range("A2:A300")

    Rng.Replace What:="~*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I just learned I want to get rid of multiple garbage symbols like "?" and "%" and "^".  Can I do multiple symbols within the same line of code, or should I write 1 line for each garbage symbol?

Comment: If you have 10-15 symbols then you could store them in an array and then use replace in a loop but for 3 symbols, 3 lines is good enough.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  My last tweak that I'd like to make is that A2:A300 can be changed to variables such that I can assign different row numbers instead of just 2 and 300.  How do I do this?

Comment: `Set Rng = ws.Range("A" & i & ":A" & j)` Where `i` and `j` are the variables